# Apache VirtualHost Error 403 You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: centos, virtualhost, httpd

I have been trying to setup this server for so long now and have been following this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) to the letter. And it works with the sample index file. But when I delete the sample index.html file, I get error 403. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Also, I know that there are already plenty of answer to this question asked by other people. And I went through most of them and yet couldn't fix my issue.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a solution instead of closing the question. Thank you :)

Comment: What reply did you expect from the server when you requested for index and there is no index file? If there is setting "Options -Indexes" somewhere, automatic directory listing is disabled. This is normal to have 403 in this case.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I am totally new to this. So what should I do?

What I wanted to do was extract wordpress files to my VirtualHost's html folder. My index.html file worked there. But my wordpress installation doesn't. And Yes, I have installed both php and MySQL as well. It looks like apache doesn't see that there is an index.php file.

Comment: Did you set up a php handler (does your server interpret php files when you reference them directly)? Have you specified an index.php to a DirectoryIndex? Which OS do you run, in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the default `index.html` you get a 403, which means "forbidden" because most likely your default apache setup it is not instructed to present directory listings.

So apache looks for `index.html` and when it can be found seeks if the client has permissions to see the directory listing and, because it is not permitted, it shows the 403 page.

You can see how to activate directory listings [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/DirectoryListings)

You can also add your own static `index.html` and you can read it as long as the user running the apache daemon can read it. If it does not have permissions you'll get again the 403 pages.

I can see also for your comments that you are trying to activate `index.php` which is a different task than the one covered by the document you're reading. Find and follow a guide on how to configure apache and mod_php like [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php/) or many others. Apache needs a module and some configuration to properly serve .php files

Answer (score 0):

When Apache is unable to find files mentioned in your directory listing, it will give you a 403 error. If you want to serve `index.php` file by default, then you need to include index.php in your `DirectoryIndex` directive and then use a PHP handler (mod_php) so that Apache can translate and serve .php files instead of just downloading them directly when accessed.